# strange GridView issue: 2 rows selected and nonexistent RowState of 3

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5, gridview, asp.net-ajax

i have a strange problem.
In RowCreated of the GridView i add following script to select a row:

```
Select Case e.Row.RowType
       Case DataControlRowType.DataRow
           e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.MainGrid, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
End Select
```

This works like a charm(i thought).
But when i debug the [SelectedIndexChanging](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanging.aspx&ei=pGfSTMbFOM2K4QbTjOyyDw&usg=AFQjCNGd66UNclm3bDP46KNMSkEqUY_GsA&sig2=H3LFVHwiafkXFswqr1dAIA) and the following [SelectedIndexChanged](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx&ei=vmfSTPmuOtSj4QamxbT0Dg&usg=AFQjCNHWINREgHAz-jCnco9psjEKj5hrYg&sig2=Fm3ipfF21vi5JsD7o2rDjg) events, i observe that the RowState of the selected Row switches from normal{0}/alternate{1} to **3** instead of selected{2}. 
This occurs between SelectedIndexChanging and SelectedIndexChanged. 
Why does this happen?

The next time i programmatically set the selectedIndex(f.e. after a new row was created), i have two rows that are selected and no (un-hacky) way to deselect the old in RowDataBound, because of the invalid [RowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowstate.aspx) of **3**(should only be 0,1,2,4 or 8).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why the RowState changes to 3, but i have a solution for the multiple selected rows. So far i set the GridView.SelectedIndex in RowDataBound:

```
  If LblPrimaryKey.Text.Equals(Me.CurrentID) Then
     Me.MainGrid.SelectedIndex = e.Row.RowIndex
  End If
```

Now i only save the new selectedIndex in a variable and set it after this:

```
  If LblPrimaryKey.Text.Equals(Me.CurrentID) Then
     selectedIndex = e.Row.RowIndex 'member variable'
     'Me.MainGrid.SelectedIndex = e.Row.RowIndex'
  End If
```

And after RowDataBound in the function that called DataBind:

```
  Me.MainGrid.DataBind()
  Me.MainGrid.SelectedIndex = Me.selectedIndex
```

Now all old selections are cleared and only one row is selected.